# Polynomiality of functions over residue rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$ is a residue ring for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If $m=p$ is  a prime number then every function $f:\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ is a polynomial $f(x) \in (\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})[x]$.

**Question:** Are there any simple criteria of polynomiality of $f$ if $m$ is composite (particularly, if $m$ is a power of a prime number or $m$ is a product of two *distinct* primes)?

**Update:** Recently I found the article [On polynomial functions $\text{(mod $m$)}$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X74900316) by D. Singmaster; there are also a series of papers by Z. Chen ([1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9500305G) and [2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X93E0162W)) about polynomial functions. One interesting result is the following:

> Let $f$ be a polynomial function $\text{(mod $m$)}$. Then $f$ has a unique polynomial representation $$f=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k x^k\quad \text{with}\quad  0 \leq b_k \leq m/(k!,m)$$ and $n$ is the least integer s.t. $m | n!$.

Comment: ( I took the liberty of editing the notation, as a member of the *International Committee for the Abolition of the Notation* $\mathbb{Z}_p$ *for Denoting Other Than p-Adic Numbers* )

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the notation, writing  $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})[x]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}[x]$ :-)

Comment: Chapter I of the book 'Polynomial Mappings' by Narkiewicz has important information about your question (but no simple answer).

Comment: @SJR: Thanks, this book is helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then a function $f:\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$ is induced by a polynomial if and only if $f$ induces well-defined functions mod $p$ and mod $q$: in other words, if and only if $f(c+p)\equiv f(c)\pmod{p}$ and $f(c+q)\equiv f(c)\pmod{q}$ for all $c\in\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$.  That polynomials have this property follows by reducing mod $p$; conversely, if a function has this property then there are polynomials $f_1,f_2\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f_1(c)\equiv f(c)\pmod{p}$ and
$f_2(c)\equiv f(c)\pmod{q}$ for all $c$.  Then the function $f$ is represented by the polynomial $qu f_1(x) + pv f_2(x)$ where $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $qu\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $pv\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

The problem is much more difficult for functions $f:\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ when $m$ is a prime power, say $m=p^n$.  One constraint is that if $f$ comes from a polynomial then $f$ must induce well-defined functions mod $p^i$ for all $i<n$.  But that is far from being sufficient.  Carlitz gave necessary and sufficient conditions for $f$ to come from a polynomial.  One such condition is that
$$
\Delta^r f(0) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{\nu(r)}}
$$
for every nonnegative integer $r$ less than $p^n$, where
$\nu(r)=\min(n, \text{ord}_p(r!))$ and $\Delta$ is the difference operator $\Delta h(c)=h(c+1)-h(c)$.  Carlitz's paper is "Functions and polynomials (mod $p^n$)", Acta Arithmetica 9 (1964), 67--78.

Comment: It's very interesting. Is it possible to obtain a similar criterium if $m=p_1p_2 \ldots p_n$, where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ are distinct primes, using this trick with Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  The result is the same as for products of two primes.  More generally, the Chinese remainder theorem lets you reduce from the case of arbitrary $m$ to the case of prime power $m$: if $m=p_1^{e_1}...p_n^{e_n}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, then a function $f$ mod $m$ comes from a polynomial if and only if $f$ induces well-defined functions mod $p_i^{e_i}$ for every $i$, and each of those functions is given by a polynomial.

Comment: @Michael: Do you know an example of a function f mod m that is well-defined mod every divisor of m but does not come from a polynomial? Could it be that simple?

Comment: @SJR: it's not that simple.  One example is when $m=p^2$ with $p$ an odd prime, where $f$ is zero except that $f(2p)=p$.  If this were a polynomial then Taylor's theorem for polynomials would imply that $f(c+p)-f(c)\equiv p f'(c)$ mod $p^2$.  For $c=0$ this gives $f'(0)\equiv 0$ mod $p$, but for $c=p$ it gives $f'(p)\equiv 1$ mod $p$, contradiction.

Comment: @Michael: I see. Very nice!

Comment: Incidentally, functions mod $p^k$ that are well-defined mod every divisor of $p^k$ are called $T$-functions. These have been studied in the cryptography and $p$-adic dynamics literature, especially by Vladimir Anashin.